# LPT passthru and RDP not working

Tags: rdp, windows-terminal-services, printer

I have RDP settings set to pass all devices thru however a device shared and captured on the local workstation is not accessible in the RDP session.

For example, if I do "type filename.txt > LPT2" or "echo foo > LPT2" I get an error stating "The system cannot find the file specified"

I have checked group policies, all pass-thru is enabled. Terminal Server is Win 2008R2.

Comment: My guess is that the device is being redirected as a printer rather than as a device connected to LPT1. Try disabling Printer Redirection and try again.

Comment: I disabled printer pass-thru but kept ports and it still errors. I also tried this on server 2012R2 and get the error. Perhaps a captured LPT ports doesn't pass-thru?